# DataSource and DriverManager on J2SE

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, connection, datasource

I'm interested in developing a desktop application that connects to a MySQL DB.
After reading [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html) java tutorial on DB connection (and several others) I have a question.
Using DataSource seems popular on J2EE while DriverManager is a common choise for desktop applications.
Is it still possible to use DataSource on a desktop application? If yes, is it a better choice over DriverManager?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's perfectly possible to use a DataSource on a desktop application.

Server apps are usually multi-thread, multi-user applications, where several connections to the database are open in parallel. A pooled DataSource is critical here.

Desktop apps are usually single-user applications, where you just need one connection to the database. So a pooled datasource isn't necessary in this case.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your reply. Should I use the com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource class to create the DataSource object in my case?

Answer (score 2):

I'll quote the javadoc:

> An alternative to the DriverManager facility, a DataSource object is the preferred means of getting a connection.

Normally you use `DriverManager` when you just want a connection for one time while with `DataSource` you get other features such as connection pooling and distributed transactions.

Hope this helps.